# How to call different functions based on optgroup using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, optgroup

I'm using select2 plugin with the below HTML and want to call different functions based on selections in different optgroups on change

```
<select data-placeholder="Select filter(s)" multiple="" class="select2 filter-boxes select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="Cars">
        <option>Audi</option>
        <option>VW</option>
        <option>BMW</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Users">
        <option>User 1</option>
        <option>User 2</option>
        <option>User 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

So for example if the user selected BMW then sortCars would be called and if user 3 was selected then sortUsers would be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 $('select').change(function(evt){
    alert(evt.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].parentElement.label);

    });
</script>
```

Learn about [events on javascript/jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: Thanks celerno, this is almost there - is there a way it can work for multiple selections, so the alert message is the label of most recent selection not always the first selection?

Comment: Sure, I put the alert label in order to show you how you can have the value of the group. If you have more than one "selectedOptions" use a for (i=0; i<selectedOptions.length; i++).

Comment: Thanks Very Much! Yes that was just what I was looking for, however it needed currentTarget in there, so the complete line was (var i = 0; i < e.currentTarget.selectedOptions.length; i++)